# Arithmetic overflow or other arithmetic exception occurred in DB2

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I am trying to calculate the gaussian pdf using sql in DB2 and have written a stored procedure.Given below is a snippet from the procedure. I have declared gaussian_value as float and try to read the value returned by the sql statement into the host variable gaussian_value. However, this gives me an error '**Arithmetic overflow or other arithmetic exception occurred in DB**'. I have tried changing the data type to double, decimal and real but am still stuck with the error. Please help!

```
declare gaussian_value float;

SET STATEMENT = 'SELECT POWER(('||stddev||'*sqrt(2*3.14)),
(SELECT POWER((-1*('||col_value||'-'||mean||')),
(2/(2*'||stddev||'*'||stddev||'))) 
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1';

                PREPARE stmt4 FROM STATEMENT;

                BEGIN 
                    DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR stmt4;
                    OPEN c1;
                    FETCH c1 into gaussian_value; -- error occurs here
                    CLOSE c1;
                END;
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why you chose such a complex way to perform the arithmetic calculations, but try to explicitly cast intermediate results in your formula to `DOUBLE`.

Comment: First, don't concatenate strings to make statements if you can avoid it, it opens you up to SQL injection - instead you should be using prepared statements.  I'm with @mustaccio, though, you don't need to go to all this trouble.  Write the thing as a regular scalar function - see [the examples near the bottom](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0003493.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-6-68).  The db will be happier if you go that route.  No need to use `SELECT`.  I suspect that one of your input parameters isn't actually numeric or something.